# Getting started with Django on Virtualbox>Vagrant>Ubuntu. Can't run django-admin

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I have a Virtual Box machine with Ubuntu installed. I also use vagrant.

I am trying to get started with Django. I have followed the steps in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/

More specifically I have performed the following steps:

```
1. Install pip

    1. Download get-pip.py
    2. $ sudo python get-pip.py
    3. $ python get-pip.py

2. Install virtualenv

    1. sudo pip install virtualenv
    2. virtualenv env --always-copy


3. Install Git

    1. $ sudo apt-get update
    2. $ sudo apt-get install git

4. Get Django into virtualenv

    1. $ cd /vagrant
    2. $ git clone git://github.com/django/django.git
```

So far so good. But in the build your own app tutorial I get a problem with the following command:

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

I get the error message:

```
The program 'django-admin' is currently not installed. To run 'django-admin' please ask your administrator to install the package 'python-django'
```

How can I get past this obstacle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't done step 4. You have not installed Django, let alone within a virtualenv; all you've done is clone the Django repo, which is unnecessary.

For step 4, you need to create a virtualenv, activate it, and install Django inside it using pip.

```
virtualenv my_django_proj
cd my_django_proj
source bin/activate
pip install django
```

Now, `django-admin startproject mysite` will work.